# Inserting Varbinary(max) with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, varbinary, scalar, varbinarymax

as per usual my google searches havent quite cleared my exact problem and i cant extract a solution from them, and i wish to understand the situation.  so here is my stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertPlayerImage @playerID varchar(9), @profileImage VARBINARY(max), @pending char(1)
AS
     INSERT INTO PlayerImage(
            playerID, 
                profileImage, 
                pending)
     VALUES(
            @playerID, 
                @playerImage, 
                @pending)
```

GO

I created the table with profileImage as a varbinary(max) and that works, the table is there.  but this procedure says i must declare the scalar variable @playerImage

i have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have put @profileImage in the Stored Procedure method, not @playerImage.

Comment: omg,  right rookie,  i just changed it prior to executing... sorry to waste your time

Comment: No problem at all! We all need a second set of eyes sometimes!